# screenorientation from landscape to portrait doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a problem in my app regarding the screenorientation.  I can rotate my screen from Portrait to Landscape without any problems, but once I rotate it from Landscape to Portrait it still displays the Landscape screen (rotated by 90°).

Answer (score 2):

This is all just guesswork because you didn't post any code, but
are you letting the activity destroy and recreate itself? If you deliberately prevent the system from re-creating the layout (by putting `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your manifest, for instance) then the system won't load the resources for the new configuration on its own anymore (particularly, if you have a different landscape layout defined, it won't know to load it). You'll want to get rid of any rotation-ignoring code like that.

Comment: From what i understand i havent done any changes to prevent the system from handling configchanges itself (although it might be an option if i cant fix the problem...), and i think i also fixed all the memleaks in my app ...

Comment: What phone are you using? Did you check "Auto-rotate screen" in display settings for your device?

Comment: its the emulator im testing on , scince we dont have any real phones ^^